# Java Regex Everything Before and Including Match

Tags: java, regex

I need the regex expression to remove any text before a match and including the match

eg. I want to remove "123S" and everything before it, I know I can do this with

```
    string.replaceAll("^.*?(?=[123S])","");
    string.replaceAll("123S","");
```

But really want to do it in a single expression (can't find another example anywhere!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
string.replaceAll("^.*123S","");
```

Remove non-greedy `?` to match last occurence and `.*` everything before.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question, but it's possible he really wants .*? so he can find the first match instead of the last.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the look ahead:

```
"abc123Sdef123Sxyz".replaceAll("^.*?123S","");
```

This replaces the *first* occurence only, if that is what you need (output is `def123Sxyz`).

In case you want to replace up to the last 123S, just remove the `?` modifier:

```
"abc123Sdef123Sxyz".replaceAll("^.*123S","");
```

Output is `xyz`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replaceAll("^.*?123S", "");
```

`(?=` is the "if followed by" pattern which you don't want, and [123S] isn't even correct it'll catch just '2' for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.replaceAll("^.*?123S","");
```

More efficient and improves clarity so someone else knows what you're doing.

Comment: I can't see any performance gain in this approach and it doesn't really answer the question.